# not adding row when i add another html file with same js file

Tags: javascript, html

when i make two seprate html than addrow are through an error and get all value null but if  i do eveything in one html than everything work fine.. please help me out

can i use onr js file in two html??
if i can use than why its through an error

my index.html code are

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Sample</title>

</head>
<body>
<p>Fname</p>
<br>
<input type="text" id="name">

<p>Lname</p>
<br>
<input type="text" id="Lname">

<p>Age:</p>
<br>
<input type="text" id="age">

<p>Email:</p>
<br>
<input type="text" id="email">
<br>
<br>

<button onclick="add()">submit</button>

<script type="text/javascript" src="add.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

secoand html file are detail.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Info List</title>
    <style type="text/css">
        table, th, td {
            border: 1px solid black;

        }
    </style>

</head>
<body>

<table style="width: 100%;" >
    <tr>
    <th>Fname</th>
    <th>Lname</th>
    <th>Age</th>
    <th>Email</th>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td id="one"></td>
        <td id="two"></td>
        <td id="three"></td>
        <td id="four"></td>
    </tr>
</table>
<script type="text/javascript" src="add.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

my js file add.js are

```
function add(){
    fname = document.getElementById('name').value
    Lname = document.getElementById('Lname').value
    age = document.getElementById('age').value
    email = document.getElementById('email').value
      console.log("helloooo")
      redirect()
      addRow(fname,Lname,age,email)

}

function redirect(){
    window.location.assign("detail.html")
}

function addRow(f,l,a,e){
       let fname = document.getElementById('one')
    let lname = document.getElementById('two')
    let  age = document.getElementById('three')
    let email = document.getElementById('four')
    fname.innerHTML = f;
    lname.innerHTML = l;
    age.innerHTML = a;
    email.innerHTML = e;
}
```

Comment: at one time only one html file will be in view. How you are loading the second one

Comment: so what can i do i need to show an data in another page

Comment: take a look at local/Session storage.

Comment: if i store a data in local storage than its fine??

Comment: show us what error you get in the console

Comment: i am getting null value in addRow function for all fname ,lname,age and email

Comment: because they exist only in the second html file detail.html and you don't have elements with these IDs in index.html

Comment: ok i got it , but what is the solution to get id value form detail.html

Answer (score 0):

You could just put all the code in the same html file:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Sample</title>

</head>
<body>
<p>Fname</p>
<br>
<input type="text" id="name">

<p>Lname</p>
<br>
<input type="text" id="Lname">

<p>Age:</p>
<br>
<input type="text" id="age">

<p>Email:</p>
<br>
<input type="text" id="email">
<br>
<br>

<button onclick="add()">submit</button>

<table style="width: 100%;" >

    <tr>
    <th>Fname</th>
    <th>Lname</th>
    <th>Age</th>
    <th>Email</th>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td id="one"></td>
        <td id="two"></td>
        <td id="three"></td>
        <td id="four"></td>
    </tr>
</table>

<script type="text/javascript" src="add.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

But really, I think your best bet would be to look into some modern framework like [react.js](https://reactjs.org/) or [Angular](https://angular.io/) - what you can do with only html+vanilla js is a bit limiting.

Comment: i am new in html and js i want to know it is possible are not in normal html css